# Ruby on Rails: want to content in grid view (matrix view)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new in Ruby On Rails. I Want my book's image and other field show in grid view (matrix view) in my index page. So I installed wice_grid gem. But when I load my index page, a popup is shown that says wice_grid.js not loaded,WiceGride cannot proceed!. I followed:

https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid.

Please help me fix this issue.

h Please tell me about this .js file and How to configure or use this file.
my controller is-

```
  class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
  @book = initialize_grid(Book, per_page: 4)
end
```

index page

```
<%= grid(@book) do |g|

g.column do |book|
image_tag book.image.url(:thumb)
end

g.column  do |book|
book.name
end

g.column do |book|
book.category
end
g.column do |book|
book.author
end
g.column do |book|
book.price
end
g.column do |book|
book.contact_no
end



end -%>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to docs

> Require WiceGrid javascript in your js index file:
>
> `//= require wice_grid`
>
> Here is an example of application.js with everything WiceGrid needs:
>
> ```
> //= require jquery 
>   //= require jquery_ujs 
>   //= require jquery-ui 
>   //= require wice_grid 
>   //= require jquery.ui.datepicker 
>   //= require_tree .
> ```

You need to add js part of gem into application.js

This file usually can be found in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

Comment: where I put these code? I know that question is basic because of I am new in this industry...

Comment: @AmitGhoshMoulick in you `application.js` file

Comment: %> %> %> %> %> %> this symbol rise in top of my index page.What is this